# Why is it that Cyclops and Havok are immune to each other's powers? Does this apply to all mutant siblings?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

I know Havok has a limited degree of energy absorption powers, but Cyclops doesn't and he's still immune to Havok's abilities.

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that they are brothers and their powers are very similar. It also stands to reason that since they can't hurt them-selves with their own power, it would make sense that they are immune to each-other's power.

Comment: http://www.comicvine.com/x-men/4060-3173/forums/which-x-men-charecters-are-related-616398/

Comment: As I recall Banshee and Black Tom, who are cousins, were also immune to each other's powers.

Comment: Pietro isn't immune to Scarlets powers.

Comment: In the Uncanny X-Men's first battle with Proteus, Cyclops specifically says that he and his brother can "metabolize" each other's blasts. And during Inferno, Havok uses his blasts to supercharge Cyclops'. So it's not just genetics; they actually absorb each other's energy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Havok has slighty more than

> A limited degree of energy absorption

Havok is constantly absorbing cosmic radiation and can absorb or drain specific energy targets.

Cyclops also does this but to a lesser degree, absorbing sunlight to charge his optic beams. He has also absorbed lightning from Storm though this caused him pain. - Uncanny Xmen Annual #3

Neither Cyclops nor Havok are fully immune to the powers of the third Summers brother Vulcan. As Vulcan is an Omega level mutant this could just be a case of his powers being too much for the others to absorb.

Interestingly Vulcan is immune to Cyclops' powers and can even control his optical blasts,
- X-Men: Deadly Genesis #4

But Vulcan is not immune to Havok's powers, which would suggest that the energy Havok releases is more powerful than Cyclops' energy.

I would say that the Summers brothers can cancel out each others powers (mostly) due to the fact that they can all emit and absorb energy.

Answer (score 1):

All the Summers' brothers powers work on an "exotic" type of energy, with Cyclop's being [arguably] the most so, in a "pure" manner. I say this because we can definitively cite the source of Havoc's powers [ambient cosmic radiation], and Vulcan's powers aren't energy based *per se,* but *psionic;* he can **mentally** control energy *on a whole,* as opposed to pulling from a specific source, making his more general.  Originally, it was thought [even by Scott himself] that sunlight "fuels" his power, which it turns out is untrue; sunlight instead seems to *feed* his body's capacity to unleash or  safely *tap into* his power, which is actually an unknown energy which stems from *a whole other dimension.** This energy gives off a ruby-colored light, but *no heat, no induction, no radio waves, no electricity*.... nothing but an intense form of concussive force.

This would put this energy *squarely* outside the electromagnetic spectrum, and most known forms of radiation. The other Summers' brothers tap into those other energies, and Vulcan can even tap into magic. However, this energy being the most "exotic" arguably means its also the most limited, which is why [generally speaking] Havoc's purely destructive power often appears to be more widespread than his brother's, and why Vulcan's is on a *whole other level.* This would *also* explain Vulcan's ability to manipulate mutant powers; on a base level, he's manipulating the energy produced from the mutant power *itself,* the energy within the body, or the electrical impulses in the mutant brain which *triggers* the ability.

All of this was necessary in order to **fully understand** the brothers' "so called"  immunity to each other's power.

It was explained that each Summers' brother is unaffected by *their own* power by generating a "natural energy field" which essentially *negates* the affect of that power on the tissues of the body. Considering the sheer *volume* of energy Vulcan can utilize, as well as the differing types, its unsurprising that he can"overwhelm" this natural defense and cause pain or damage with their brother' powers.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read in comics and seen on cartoon series,  mutant siblings powers either cancel each other out or can boost one another's in some instances like with Havoc and Cyclops and Black Tom and Banshee whom were a pair of siblings.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for the cancelling out theory you could [edit] in?

Comment: This isn't usually the case. True, there _are_ examples for both, but I believe with siblings, it's more of them instinctively knowing how to work with the other for certain effects as opposed to a type of "biological negation".  Quicksilver and Wanda's powers have no real effect on each other, but they work well together. Wolverine's kids powers have no reaction, either. NorthStar & Aurora can feed off/enhance each other, but they're _twins, specifically adapted_ to that. Racheal Summers has never shown any type of "synergy" with her siblings Cable or X-Man; they're just all strong psychics

Answer (score -2):

Well how about we try this instead, why shouldn't their powers not work on one another? Is there a reasonable plot reason for them not to do so? Is their any benefit from them not doing? Nope. It's a more interesting facet of the lore that they don't and gave writers something to explore over time.
So the real answer is so the stories aren't boring.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Instead of posing your answer in the form of a question, it should be phrased as a definite statement, which you should lead with and _then_ explore.  This answer is also an out-of-universe which is less preferred than in-universe answers and generally requires some evidence from the creators.